# Why the entry widget state in tkinter is depend on print function? Oo

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

When I try to toggle the state of the Entry widget, the state is toggled but fails in the match-case loop unless the state is displayed with print function.

There are two conditions in the combobox here. Depending on the conditions, entry widgets are turned on and off. This code work fine for me:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def change_condition_types(*args):
    match var.get():
        case 'Condition 1':
            entry1['state'] = 'normal'
            entry2['state'] = 'disabled'

        case 'Condition 2':
            entry1['state'] = 'disabled'
            entry2['state'] = 'normal'


def validate():
    for entry in (entry1, entry2):
        print('State: ', entry['state'])

        match entry['state']:
            case 'normal':
                print('Entry ON \nEntry: ', entry)
            case 'disabled':
                print('Entry OFF \nEntry: ', entry)
            case _:
                print('Why am i here?')
                print('Entry: ', entry)


# Window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x500')

# Widgets
ttk.Button(window, text='Validate!', command=validate).pack()
entry1 = ttk.Entry(window)
entry1.pack(pady=10)
entry2 = ttk.Entry(window)
entry2.pack(pady=10)

conditions = ['Condition 1', 'Condition 2']
var = tk.StringVar(value=conditions[0])
combobox = ttk.Combobox(master=window, values=conditions, textvariable=var, state='readonly')
combobox.pack()
var.trace('w', change_condition_types)

# First state
entry2.configure(state='disabled')

window.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
State:  normal
Entry ON 
Entry:  .!entry
State:  disabled
Entry OFF 
Entry:  .!entry2
```

But when i try to comment print line in validate function like this, i have another result:

```py
def validate():
    for entry in (entry1, entry2):
        # print('State: ', entry['state'])

        match entry['state']:
            case 'normal':
                print('Entry ON \nEntry: ', entry)
            case 'disabled':
                print('Entry OFF \nEntry: ', entry)
            case _:
                print('Why am i here?')
                print('Entry: ', entry)
```

Result:

```
why am i here?
Entry:  .!entry
why am i here?
Entry:  .!entry2
```

Comment: I think it is some kind of optimization by the Python interpreter.  Note that `entry['state']` is a class object actually, so the `print(...)` will cast it to a string which **may be cached** and used by the latter `match` statement.  Without the `print(...)`, `entry['state']` is not treated as a string.  It works when using `match str(entry['state'])`.

Comment: It seems to be true! Thanks, problem solved. Don't know, how to mark your comment as an answer. May be If you repost it as answer, i will do it